Laravel Passport token request times out
I am using Laravel 11 and need to setup passport for authentication
Installation:
php artisan install:api --passport

Password grand setup
php artisan passport:client --password

The prompt suggested a name for the password grant and I pressed.
Ultimately it asked the following:
Which user provider should this client use to retrieve users?
I pressed enter, the client id & secret were generated, and I pasted them in my .env
.env
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID=client-id
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_SECRET=client-secret

I added the following to config/auth.php
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],

Lastly, I added the following to the boot method of AppServiceProvider
Passport::enablePasswordGrant();

In api.php, I am attempting to request a token using a login route:
Route::post('/login', function(Request $request) {

    $request_url = env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token';

    $response = Http::asForm()->post($request_url, [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_SECRET'),
        'username' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' => '',
    ]);
    
    return response()->json([
       'data' => $response->json()
    ]);
}

In postman, I created a post request for
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login

and set the body tab to form data
I see the following error when I hit the send button:
cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30006 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token

Is there anything I am missing in my setup?

The error message you are getting is a result of server failing to respond to data requests in a timely manner. The post request within the login route takes a long time to return a response with oauth-token resulting to "cURL error 28".
$request_url = env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token';
$response = Http::asForm()->post($request_url, [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_SECRET'),
    'username' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password,
    'scope' => '',
]);
return response()->json([
   'data' => $response->json()
]);

Replace the above code with the code below to altenatively retrieve your personal access token.
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
   $user = Auth::user();
   $user['token'] = $user->createToken('Token-name')->accessToken;
   return response()->json(['data' => $user]);
}else {
   return response()->json(['errors' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

Also, since you are requesting an oauth-token you ought to authenticate the user performing the login request with credentials (email and password)
